# Android application that can keep track of where I am located + can replay it on a map

Tags: android, maps, history, travel

I am looking for an Android application that can keep track of where I am located when I'm driving or walking, and then can replay the path on a map in real-time (e.g., if I drove for 1h, show the location of my car in a 1h video on a map). I'm ok if the replay involves the use of a computer.

Example of replay (but in my case, I want it to be real-time):

[image]

Any license and price is fine.

Comment: I only know such a feature from Google Earth on Windows. Supplied with a GPX track you can move a time-slider and see the position related to the selected time on the map.

Comment: I'm not sure which app has the replay feature, and you didn't name license/price (you usual "any OS, any price" phrase is missing #D) – but maybe my app list on [Tracking (general)](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_tracking) can help you out? From that list, candidates that *sound* promising are Enduro, HelloTracks, maybe also GPS Logger. I've not tried any of them, so I cannot tell for sure or give a clear recommendation.

Comment: @Izzy thanks, I'll look at the list, any license and price is fine :)

Comment: @Robert Thanks, indeed I see https://support.google.com/earth/answer/183681?hl=en, if we find some compatible Android application to record the GPS coordinates, that'd be a nice solution.